# Prevent people from opening raw images

Tags: html, css, image

I want to create a page on a site where I can place images up in a slideshow. 
Normally, this would be very simple, but I'm trying to do something else...

I want to try and stop people from accessing the image by typing the image URL into their browser, but allow the image to show if it's called within my webpage, and, if possible, my webpage alone.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: @PaulRoub I was just about to flag the same duplicate, but it's not actually a duplicate of that question after all.

Comment: @nkorth I retracted my close vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

where are your images stored?  If you are using the likes of amazon s3, you can set rules for setting images to be private and only accessible by say, your application.

This may help a little.. http://improve.dk/how-to-set-up-and-serve-private-content-using-s3/